# prisma introspect generate invalid model

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma

Prisma version         : ^2.26.0

Prisma/client          : ^2.26.0

@relation error msg in : Error parsing attribute "@relation": The type of the field `userId` in the model `posts` is not matching the type of the referenced field `id` in model `users`.

---

Why prisma created invalid model or something wrong with my code after i run ***npx prisma introspect***?

It cause cannot to enter the **prisma studio** since those error in my code.

Any solution or thought could share to make me know better for this?

Below is my sql:

```
-- Create a custom type
CREATE TYPE "user_role_enum" AS ENUM ('user', 'admin', 'superadmin');

-- Create a table
CREATE TABLE "users"(
    "id" BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "email" VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    "role" user_role_enum NOT NULL DEFAULT('user')
);

-- Create a table
CREATE TABLE "posts"(
    "id" BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "title" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "body" TEXT,
    "userId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES "users"("id")
);

-- Create data
INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "role")
VALUES('John Doe', 'john@email.com', 'admin'),
('jane Doe', 'jane@email.com', 'admin'),
('Ahmed Hadjou', 'ahmed@hadjou.com', 'user');

INSERT INTO "posts" ("title", "body", "userId")
VALUES('Hello World!!', 'Hey guys, I see a rainbow through this prisma :D', 1),
('So do I', 'It looks cooool!!!', 2),
('It does', 'Yeahhh', 1);
```

Generate for model from prisma introspect

```
model posts {
  id     BigInt  @id @default(autoincrement())
  title  String  @db.VarChar(255)
  body   String?
  userId Int
  users  users   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id]) // Error parsing attribute "@relation": The type of the field `userId` in the model `posts` is not matching the type of the referenced field `id` in model `users`.
}

model users {
  id    BigInt         @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String         @db.VarChar(255)
  email String         @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  role  user_role_enum @default(user)
  posts posts[] // error in here
}

enum user_role_enum {
  user
  admin
  superadmin
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more context into the problem. Here a few things that would help: 1. Which version of prisma and prisma studio are you using?  2. What exact error does prisma studio show?  3. Is the issue with Studio or the client as well? 4. Can you use the prisma client to perform CRUD operations on the introspected models?

Comment: posts.userId and users.id must both be Bigint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change Int to BigInt userId in Post Model , it will work

Comment: Thanks! i'd try it later!

Comment: yeah, it works! Could i know what is the reason why the Int is not accpetable?

Comment: type issue, In model users you mentioned id as BidInt but in Post model you mentioned userId Int, that is the reason, If my answer works please make my answer mark as solved for others to let it works.